# Get the last rows for a unique value in a column from a dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excerpt of a dataframe `df` below:

```
    Player          Trial       Score                          
0   Josh              1         1     
1   Josh              2         3 
2   Josh              3         2 
3   Josh              4         2 
4   Josh              5         2 
5   Josh              6         5    
6   Josh              7         2 
0   Yuli              1         1     
1   Yuli              2         3 
2   Yuli              3         2 
3   Yuli              4         2 
4   Yuli              5         2 
0   Max               1         4     
1   Max               2         6   
2   Max               3         10   
3   Max               4         10  
4   Max               5         17  
5   Max               6         10  
6   Max               7         14
```

I would like to select the last rows which has a unique value for the 'Player' column i.e.

```
   Player          Trial       Score    
0   Max               1         4     
1   Max               2         6   
2   Max               3         10   
3   Max               4         10  
4   Max               5         17  
5   Max               6         10  
6   Max               7         14
```

I have tried `df.groupby("Player").tail()` but this only returns the last 5 rows for each player. I have also tried a rather lengthy method:

```
df.groupby('Trial').tail().loc[df['Player'] == df['Player'].unique()[-1]]
```

This gives me what I want but I am sure I am missing a cleaner method. Any help would be appreciated to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Why Max and not Josh

Comment: ```df.groupby(["Player","Trial"]).tail(3)```  @S23 ?

Comment: I would like to always select the tail end of the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your response @DeanTaler, but I would like to avoid specifying the value '3' as I am not always sure that there will be 3, or less or more.

Comment: @S23 you can write any value you want or no specify at all

Comment: @DeanTaler Yes, but without specifying a value in `tail()`, it only returns the last 5 rows. I have only shown an excerpt of the dataframe, as the full dataframe has more rows for each player.

Comment: I think the ambiguities will be resolved if you can add a proper expected output please?

Comment: @sophocles Thank you for your suggestion. I have made an edit to show my expected output.

Comment: I still don't understand why this isn't `df.groupby('Trial').tail(1)`.

Comment: Thank you @HenryYik that gives me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you just want to get all the rows of the final player (i.e the name in the last row of your `df` in Player column.

```
last_player = df.Player.iloc[-1]
df.loc[df.Player==last_player]
```

which prints:

```
   Player  Trial  Score
7     Max      1      4
8     Max      2      6
9     Max      3     10
10    Max      4     10
11    Max      5     17
12    Max      6     10
13    Max      7     14
```

Be aware the sorting your `df`, in a different way, will highly likely alter the output of the above code.